# How to show two images in one slide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bxslider

Am using bxslider in my rails app it works fine. It shows one image per slide but i want is to show two images per slide.

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <% @highlights.each do |highlight| %>
  <% if highlight.area == current_or_guest_user.search_area or highlight.state == current_or_guest_user.search_state or highlight.city == current_or_guest_user.search_city %>
  <li><%= image_tag highlight.image, :class => "dali" %></li>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

if i replicate the image_tag it does show two images in one slide but the same image.

Comment: This behavior is defined inside the javascript plugin. There's no option to do that so if you want to display two images and adapt their size, you have to edit the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the records in pairs. Try this:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <% @highlights.each_cons(2) do |highlight1, highlight2| %>
    <% if condition %>
      <li class="row">
        <%= image_tag highlight1.image, :class => "dali col-xs-6" %>
        <%= image_tag highlight2.image, :class => "dali col-xs-6" %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```